# Why cannot `f2fs_delete_entry` be traced by bpftrace

Tags: linux, trace, bpf, bcc, bpftrace

I use the following command to trace function `f2fs_delete_dentry`:

```
bpftrace -e 'kprobe:f2fs_delete_entry {printf("comm:%s inode:%ld\n", comm, ((struct inode*)arg3)->i_ino); }'
```

But it does not print anything.

So I use `bpftrace -lv "t:f2fs:f2fs_delete_entry"` to check it. I prints nothing yet. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I know of:

- That function is not executed while you are tracing.
- This function has multiple call sites. On the path you know is executed, this function has been inlined. Thus, bpftrace is actually tracing only other call sites.